# Initialize a structure with a set of constant structures in C

Tags: c, visual-c++, struct

I'm writing a device driver in MSVC. As part of design I want to have different modules but have the modules somewhat isolated from each other so that they are interchangeable in the future. My design has a structure with the following declaration

```
typedef struct tagMODULE_INTERFACE {
  NTSTATUS (*initialize)(GLOBAL_DATA *pGD);
  NTSTATUS (*shutdown)(void);
  NTSTATUS (*sendResponse)(PVOID outBuf, ULONG outBufSz, PULONG outBufLen); 
} MODULE_INTERFACE, *PMODULE_INTERFACE;
```

In the main .c file I have my main array of modules to load at install time. It is defined as such:

```
MODULE_INTERFACE modules[2] = 
{
    Module1, 
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}// terminal entry
};
```

In my module1.c file I expose the following:

```
CONST MODULE_INTERFACE Module1 = {initializeModule1, shutdownModule1, sendModule1Response};
```

In my module1.h file I have:

```
extern CONST MODULE_INTERFACE Module1;
```

The idea here is that I don't have to declare initializeModule1, shutdownModule1 and sendModule1Response functions outside of module1.c, but the main.c will have an array of function pointers to use to initialize, shutdown and callback whenever necessary.

My problem is that I'm getting a C2099 "initialize is not a constant" error for the Module1 entry in modules and I'm getting C2078 "too many initializers" for the {NULL, NULL, NULL} entry.

What am I missing here? I thought originally that if I ensured that module1.c compiled ahead of main.c it would solve the first problem, but it didn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need the stuff in main.c.  Especially if both main.c and module1.c #include module1.h.  Just delete it, and see if Life becomes Good :)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. the main.c's modules[2] is an array of modules to activate while Module1 in module1.c is one MODULE_INTERFACE structure. If i'm right, then modules[2] should be effective modules[2] = {MODULE_INTERFACE, MODULE_INTERFACE} types, right?